# Difference between these two codes?

Tags: python, function, return, definition

```
def Dishlist_all_cheap(d: [Dish], x: int):
    for i in d:
        if Dish_is_cheap(i, x) == False:
            return False
    return True
```

vs.

```
def Dishlist_all_cheap(d: [Dish], x: int):
    for i in d:
        if Dish_is_cheap(i, x) == False:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Why and how does the placement of the "return True" statement matter? For background purposes, the function Dish_is_cheaper says whether or not a dish is cheaper than the stated price, while Dishlist_all_cheap says whether or not ALL dishes within a list is cheaper than the stated price.

Comment: `return all(Dish_is_cheap(dish, x) for dish in d)`

Comment: You could also say `if not Dish_is_cheap(i, x):`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Does it matter what a Dish is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code didn't work well :

```
def Dishlist_all_cheap(d: [Dish], x: int):
    for i in d:
        if Dish_is_cheap(i, x) == False:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Because it returns *`True`* if the first `Dish` of the list is cheap. You want to return *`True`* if all the `Dish`es are cheaper

It's this code which does that well:

```
def Dishlist_all_cheap(d: [Dish], x: int):
    for i in d:
        if Dish_is_cheap(i, x) == False:
            return False
    return True
```

It returns *`True`* if the `Dish_is_cheap(i, x)` is always *`True`* for all the dishes.